# How do metrics providers, such as metrics-server and prometheus-adapter, register it's api to kubernetes apiserver

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubernetes-apiserver

You can easily access metrics through Kubernetes-apiserver, such as `curl http://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/pods`(in kubectl proxy mode). Not like object-access apis, metrics are from some other components like metrics-server(`kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-system metrics-server`). How can I design my own metrics provider, and expose my own RESTful API on Kubernetes-apiserver.

I went through a lot of code in Kubernetes and [Prometheus Adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter), but so far not a clue.

So any code references to this topic? Thx in advance:D

Comment: Hi, this might be useful https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/setup-extension-api-server/#setup-an-extension-api-server-to-work-with-the-aggregation-layer

Comment: @SureshVishnoi It's not exactly what i want. Metrics are different from other resources stored in ETCD.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but take a look at custom metrics adapter libraries -  https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/custom-metrics-apiserver

Comment: In general, it's done with the [Kubernetes API aggregation layer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/apiserver-aggregation/).